# Updating after delete | mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables for example table1 and table2. If something is deleted in table1 i want to update a column in table2. Is this even possible with a trigger in phpmyadmin? if yes what do i have to add or which syntax i have to use for it to work?

I tried this so far:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `update` AFTER DELETE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
-- this is the part i dont know what to do and i couldnt find any related to my task

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This is almost the same as the previous question you raised today. How would you update a table outwith a trigger?

Comment: But only almost

Comment: 'this is the part i dont know what to do and i couldnt find any related to my task' - you could try reading the manual 'Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger' dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html - ie use OLD. values to update table2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in your TRIGGER you can access the value you just deleted with `OLD.your_column_name`.

So just do :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `update` AFTER DELETE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

UPDATE table2 SET column_name = your_new_value WHERE column_name = OLD.old_value;

END//
DELIMITER ;
```