# How to UPDATE or DELETE data in one table and reflect that change in another table

Tags: c#, mysql

Basically, let's say I have 5 members that I've inserted into my database and memeber #1 is selected in team Lakers, member #2 is selected in team Knicks, member 3 is in team Hornets, member #4 is in team OKC and member #5 is in team Dallas. And if I delete team Knicks I need to update member #2 automatically to not be anymore selected in team Knicks as that data doesn't exist anymore, I want member #2 team to be empty.

I'll post pictures of my app tomorrow and explain further if I need to. Hopefully someone will understand what I'm asking and what I want to do.

Comment: use troggers to update after Delete like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526265/updating-after-delete-mysql-trigger

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a linking table.

For example:

`tbl_player`: `player_id`, `player_name`

`tbl_team`: `team_id`, `team_name`

the linking table will be like this:

`tbl_teamplayers`: `team_id`, `player_id`

and you should set the table columns with `DELETE` and `UPDATE` `CASCADE` rules

so if you delete a team or a player, the link data will automatically be deleted.